# How to smooth out a WPF gradient?

Tags: c#, wpf, render, gradient

I want to best render RadialGradientBrush in my wpf application.
This is my XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF3A3A3A" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF323232"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

This is WPF render:

[image: WPF image]

I change this in Photoshop render (check the Dither in gradient overly):

[image: Photoshop image]

Comment: You should upload the pictures to somewhere else. It seems SO is downsampling the images, so we don't see the problem.

Comment: Look at this:
http://www.iceflowstudios.com/2013/tips/smooth-gradients-in-photoshop-dithering/
you can fix this in photoshop but i cannot fix this in wpf

Comment: There is no dither setting in WPF, but +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: @Euphoric actually, if you look really closely you see the bands in the first image. The link provided helped because then I knew what to look for.

Comment: It's just not possible without dithering (WPF does not support dithering on their standard brushes). There is so much a 24-bit display can show: exactly 256 steps if you take a single component, or all three components must be the same (as in your example). If the gradient ocurs over a larger area than 256 pixels, banding will ocur and there's no standard workaround around this.

You could do a shader using the GPU which does dithering, but that's far from being a general solution and it's not without its side effects.

Comment: If you go the GPU route, this link might prove useful as a starting point: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2008/05/12/a-series-on-gpu-based-effects-for-wpf.aspx (or directly using `ShaderEffect`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect(v=vs.110).aspx)