# Is it possible to use dithering on a WPF gradient?

Tags: c#, wpf, dithering

I wondered if it is possible to use dithering (e.g. Floyd-Steinberg) on the WPF gradient?

XAML:

```
<RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" Center="0.5,0.5">
    <GradientStop Color="#333333" Offset="0"></GradientStop>           
    <GradientStop Color="#111111" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
</RadialGradientBrush>
```

Comment: This question was asked many times. It can be done but it's complicated. I've never tested it. Check out some tricks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801524/how-to-make-the-brush-smooth-without-lines-in-the-middle or a real solution like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541873/how-to-smooth-out-a-wpf-gradient?noredirect=1&lq=1  where Jcl suggested to use the GPU for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like that built into WPF.

You would need to write your own code to do it.

One possible way to achieve it would be to write a custom HLSL pixel shader effect. You could probably apply the dithering algorithms there. Over the years I've written various custom shaders, and this seems like the best approach.

This should get you started:
https://bytelanguage.net/2018/11/10/shaders-with-hlsl-for-wpf-developers/